# How do I interprete a greyscale matlab image passed to my c++ mexFunction

Tags: image, matlab, mex

Here is my project, I have a GUI that loads images and I need to pass this image and several information to my mexFunction coded in C++, like xSize, ySize, window size for processing.  I am having trouble to interprete the information that matlabs gives me and I am not sure how to actually do it too.

Comment: you would treat the image as any other matrix. please refer to the MEX documentation.

Comment: I understand that it is a matrix, but not how the information is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the type of the data of your matrix?
I think that `imread` returns a matrix of size m*n*3 of type uint8.
try taking the example above and change the definition of `input` to:

```
unsigned char *input;
```

(since `double` takes four times the memory is `uint8` you get memory exceptions when you treat the pointer as pointer to `double`).

Answer (score 1):

When you pass any matrix to a MEX function, it is stored as a 1D array in a column-major order. Thus it is fastest to access it sequentially using linear indices.

In the case of an image, you can access it as a 2D matrix if you prefer, you just need to map row/column indices to linear indices with a simple calculation.

Consider this example:

#### matrixExample.c

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mwSize r,c, i,j, n;
    double *input;

    /* get size of the matrix */
    r = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    c = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

    /* get pointer to data */
    input = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);

    /* access matrix using row/column indices */
    for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<c; j++) {
            mexPrintf("%lf ", input[j*r+i]);
        }
        mexPrintf("\n");
    }

    /* access matrix using linear indices (column-major) */
    n = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        mexPrintf("%lf\n", input[i]);
    }
}
```

Compile this MEX function:

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims matrixExample.c
```

Then you can use it on sample matrix:

```
>> matrixExample( rand(2,3) )

0.646204 0.592287 0.464080 
0.668417 0.740318 0.143579 

0.646204
0.668417
0.592287
0.740318
0.464080
0.143579
```

Note that I skipped doing input checking just to keep the example simple..

Everything should be explained in the documentation, so start by reading the [users guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f7667.html), and refer to the [API reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/bqoqnz0.html) when needed.

The are also a number of examples included with MATLAB you can study:

```
>> winopen( fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','mex') )
>> winopen( fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','mx') )
```

Comment: when I get dismensions from mxGetDimension I get 3 dimensions. So I tried image[(x*j+i)]) to get red Channel (image[(1*x*y)+(x*j+i)]) to get green Channel and  image[(2*x*y)+(x*j+i)])  where x and y are my image dimension and i,j are my indices to access the good coordinate in the image.  But I get an segfault when I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the the MATLAB help for [imread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html). It's quite detailed.